# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT ( Could not cast value of type )

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I'm making an iOS app using swift3 on xcode8.

My storyboard is this ( [storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oFCH.png) ).

If I click the button on the third TableViewController from the left, the fourth one will appear. The fourth one is a ViewController to choose library or camera to place a photo onto the imageView on the third TableViewController.

I write the function below in the fourth ViewController's file. The function is a method called when a photo is taken or chosen.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    if info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] != nil {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            let navigationController = self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController

            let originVc = navigationController.topViewController as! SettingTableViewController

            originVc.image = image

            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

When this is run, `let navigationController = self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController` part is highlighted, and says `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`. And also the error `Could not cast value of type '[APPNAME].ViewController' to 'UINavigationController' (0x10f85c4a8).` is shown(*[APPNAME] is my app name).

Do you know anything about this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because your self.presentingViewController  is not navigation controller

Comment: Get rid of the `as!` casts and set a debugger breakpoint that lets you see the **real** object types being assigned.  It will tell you where you went wrong more quickly that a question on SO.  :)

Comment: Thanks for comments! Actually, it should be navigation controller because if I make exactlly the same one in another project, it works. However, it doesn't work in my current project. By the way, the third TableViewController's type is SettingTableViewController, so I tried this "let originVc = self.presentingViewController as! SettingTableViewController" instead, but the same error still appears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This crash is telling you that your `presentingViewController` **is not** an `UINavigationController`, in fact is a `UIViewController`, so you need to use the `.navigationController` property and use a `if let` or `guard` to avoid any problem

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let navigationController = self.presentingViewController.navigationController{

               let originVc = navigationController.topViewController as! SettingTableViewController

               originVc.image = image

               self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I do that, the codes inside "if let" wasn't run. But as I wrote in the comment of my question now, even "let originVc = self.presentingViewController as! SettingTableViewController" didn't work.

Comment: check if `self.presentingViewController` is not nil

Comment: I checked it now. It wasn't nil. By the way, the type is "Optional<UIViewController>".

Comment: check if `self.presentingViewController.navigationController` is not nil

Comment: by the way I can see your storyboard image your image server is forbidden for my country ;)

Comment: It was nil. Oh really?! I should use another service then ;)

Comment: can you post your image in Igmur? @Yutaro

Comment: I added! Thanks for telling me!

Comment: check your transition type from second to third view controllers must be push type @Yutaro

Comment: check your transition type from second to third view controllers must be push type @Yutaro

Comment: How can I check it? I just connected the top left setting button on the second one with the third one using "show".

Comment: in the segue created touch and check if segue type is push??

Comment: check in your viewDidAppear fo your third viewController if self.navigationController is nil

Comment: self.navigationController was nil.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It wasn't nil ;)